# View text inside img alt in <p>

Tags: jquery

I tried to print the text that contains within the alt attribute in a tag

html

```
<p class="name-item-slider"></p>

<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li><img src="car.png" class="drag-item" alt="Scissors" ></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
var namealt = $("img").alt();
$(".name-item-slider").html(namealt);
```

Comment: There is no `alt()` method, either in jquery or native javascript (unless you made a custom one). The browser should be showing you a runtime error. This is why your code is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("p.name-item-slider").text($("img.drag-item").attr("alt"));
```

Or if you want to break it up:

```
//Get the text
var altText = $("img.drag-item").attr("alt");

//Set the text
$("p.name-item-slider").text(altText);
```

Comment: perfect. and if I wanted to attack from the class <li class="flex-active-slide"> how about it?

Comment: @Maria -- You want the text from that `li` or you want to replace the text of that `li`?

Comment: $("img.drag-item").attr("class") ?

Comment: I need (li).flex-active-slide>img>alt""

Comment: `$("li.flex-active-slide").find("img").attr("alt");`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a div with the class of flexslider, I imagine you are working some sort of image slideshow, or at least something where multiple `<img>` tags are used. If that is the case, then you will need a more robust answer than just getting the alt from one image and putting it in a p tag.

That is, if you have several `<p>` and `<img>` tags then this will not work:

```
$('p').text($('img').attr('alt'));
```

Actually, it will work, but not the way you want it to. It will only get the alt from the first matched image and the p tag text will persist with that content. To update the p tag with the correct alt you will need a loop.

I've never used flexslider, but I'm sure it has a callback function. In side that you will need something like this:

```
$('.name-item-slider').text($('.img.drag-item.current-slide').attr('alt'));
```